# Prove the sequence $f_{n} = \frac{1}{n^2+1}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

Prove the sequence $f_{n} = \frac{1}{n^2+1}$ is a cauchy sequence.

I'm just making sure my logic and reasoning is sound for the above proof:

**Definition of cauchy sequence:** $f_n$ is Cauchy if for all $Ɛ$ there is an $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n,m > M,
|f_n-f_m|<Ɛ$

$|f_n-f_m|$=$|\frac{1}{n^2+1}-\frac{1}{m^2+1}|$

**by the triangle inequality:**

$\le|\frac{1}{n^2+1}|+|\frac{1}{m^2+1}|$

$<\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}$

To ensure $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}<Ɛ$ it suffices to have:

$max(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}) < \frac{Ɛ}{2} $, so we will take $M(Ɛ) = \lceil\frac{2}{Ɛ}\rceil$

***Now for a formal proof:***

Let $Ɛ>0$

Define $M(Ɛ) = \lceil\frac{2}{Ɛ}\rceil$

Let $n,m > M(Ɛ)$

$n,m > \frac{2}{Ɛ}$

$\frac{1}{n}<\frac{Ɛ}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{m}<\frac{Ɛ}{2}$

$|f_n - f_m| \le \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}$

$|f_n - f_m| < \frac{Ɛ}{2}+\frac{Ɛ}{2} = Ɛ$

Therefore $f_n$ is cauchy.

**Solution to the proof**
[image: solutions]

Comment: Yes, your proof is fine.

Comment: Okay great, I was just checking as if you see in my question above, the solution was different. I thought my answer was too simple.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: The proof before the red edit is fine.